# Node 'progress' module, ticking with an error

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, progress

I'm using the wildly node module [progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress) but am having an issue where if I execute it after a try...catch block, it does not render correctly if an error is caught.

For example:

```
const bar = new progBar('[:bar] File :token1: :token2 \n', {
  total: filesArray.length,
});

for (let i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i += 1) {
  const file = filesArray[i];
  let result;

  try {
    result = getStuff(file) || 'Nothing returned.';
  } catch (e) {
    result = e.toString();
  }

  bar.tick({
    token1: file,
    token2: result,
  });

  if (bar.complete) {
    console.log('\nComplete\n');
  }
}
```

Renders each returned result as expected, unless there the catch statement is fired, then the bar does not even attempt to display that result (ideally, the bar plus error)... it just skips those ticks and continues displaying...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
const bar = new progBar('[:bar] File :token1: :token2', {
  total: filesArray.length,
});
```

Problem is not `try catch`, because your progBar has a new line.
Remove`\n`, you just log in one line.

Comment: Actually, it behaves the same (skips output for the caught token)... the newline simply pushes each bar output to a new line instead of overwriting in place (easier to see what happened).